# React Server-Side Rendering (SSR) Error with styled-components Button in Next.js 13.4.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I am currently developing a React application using Next.js version 13.4.1 and styled-components. I'm experiencing an issue with my custom Button component as follows:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface ButtonProps {
  $primary?: boolean;
}

const Button = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  background: red;
`;

const Nav: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button>Primary Button</Button> // this one
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

The issue arises when I attempt to run the application with the command `npm run dev`. An Unhandled Runtime Error is thrown, with the following details:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <button> in <div>.
```

Upon inspecting the source code, I found that the `<button>` element is not being rendered, as the error message suggests.

I am unable to understand why the  is not being rendered in the server HTML. I have the above code in a file named "Nav.tsx" which I import into "page.tsx".

How can I resolve this issue and ensure my `<Button>` component is correctly rendered by the server? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems styled-components causes this.

Comment: styled-components 6.0.0-rc.1 works fine with next@13.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `styled-components` is supported in client components of `app directory`. [you can read from here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js)

> The following libraries are supported in Client Components in the app
> directory:
>
> - styled-jsx
> - styled-components
> - tamagui
> - style9
> - vanilla-extract

If you convert the current component to client with `use client` directive, your code will work

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. My bad, I missed the documentation you mentioned.